# How to extract embeddings of categorical variables

Tags: python, data-science-model, embeddings

I am little bit confused about encoding categorical variables. There are other posts/blogposts on this issue but none is talking about the problem I am facing.

I have a dataset with mixed variables (i.e, numerical as well as categorical). Some of the categorical variables has a lot of categories (close to 100). So instead of using `One Hot encoders`, I am looking into using embeddings.

My goal is to: Use the embeddings of the categorical variables and extract them and put them together with my numerical variables to form the design/training matrix and then run an autoencoder on it (the reason to run autoencoder is to detect anomalous data ).

I have put together a code snippet (see below) but what confuses me is to how to `extract the embeddings to put it together with my numerical variables`. I need to know because when new data shows up, I need the embeddings to run it through prediction to isolate any "odd" datapoint from the reconstruction error.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Concatenate, Reshape, Dropout
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding

inputs = []
embeddings = []

# for categorical variables
for cat in cat_model_vars:
    inp = Input(shape=(1,))
    inputs.append(inp)
    emb = Embedding(cat_sizes[cat]+1,cat_embedding_size[cat], input_length=1,name=f"{cat}_embedding")(inp)
    emb = Reshape(target_shape=(cat_embedding_size[cat],))(emb)
    embeddings.append(emb)

# for continuous/numerical variables

inp_num = Input(shape=(len(num_model_vars),),name='cont_vars')
emb_num = Dense(10)(inp_num)
inputs.append(inp_num)
embeddings.append(emb_num)

# concatenate the embeddings, this is going to be input to our Autoencoder model
output = Concatenate()(embeddings)

#%%

# build a stacked Autoencoder below and feed the output as it's input and output

en_x = Dense(50, activation = 'relu')(output)
en_x = Dense(32, activation = 'relu')(en_x)
en_x = Dense(16, activation = 'relu')(en_x)
en_x = Dense(4, activation = 'relu')(en_x)

de_x = Dense(16, activation = 'relu')(en_x)
de_x = Dense(32, activation = 'relu')(de_x)
de_x = Dense(50, activation = 'relu')(de_x)

output = Dense(25, activation = 'relu')(de_x)

stacked_ae_model = Model(inputs, output)
stacked_ae_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='Adam',
                         metrics=['mse','mape'])

"""NEED TO EXTRACT THE EMBEDDINGS THAT ARE USED AS AN INPUT TO THE STACKED AUTOENCODER (NOT DONE YET)"""
```

Now I will have to run the training and prediction. But I am not sure how to extract the embeddings so that I can use those for training.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

It you have a model with multiple inputs you have to pass the dataframe into model as a dictionary of rows. Split the dataframe into 2 dataframes - categorical and numerical. 
Categorical dataframe convert into a dictionary by `train_df.to_dict('list')` and merge into it the numerical dataframe as 1 multidimensional feature with name "cont_vars".
You should also name all input columns:

```
for cat in cat_model_vars:
   inp = Input(shape=(1,), name=cat)

inp_num = Input(shape=(len(num_model_vars),),name='cont_vars')
```

Update dataframe (not tested):

```
train_df2 = train_df[cat_model_vars]
train_df2['cont_vars'] = train_df[cont_model_vars].values.tolist()
train_df = train_df2
```

Example of how to convert pandas dataframes to tensors:

```
test_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test_df.to_dict('list')).batch(BATCH_SIZE).cache()
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_df.to_dict('list'), labels)).shuffle(10000).batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True).cache()
```

Finally, train and predict the model:

```
model.fit(train_data, epochs=100)
y_pred_test = model.predict(test_data, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```